# How do you look at the body of a user made function in python?

Tags: python

What command do you use to look at the body or arguments of a user made function in python?

Thanks

Comment: "Body or arguments"?

Comment: You may have luck with the `inspect` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html
But normally you don't need to do this. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Say I create my own function.                                                                                    def my_function(arg):                                                                                                         
                  **x + arg = something                                                                                     
                  return something**                                                                              How do I review the bold text.

Comment: @ZachRickers The `inspect` module is your best bet. Are you trying to automate reviewing someone else's code? If you are doing this in your own code or package? If so, there is probably a better way for the overall problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I'm using datacamp.com and sometimes they have functions that they have been made in previous exercises.  I would just like to be able to review the body of the code without having to dig in previous exercises.  I know R has a function **body(function)** which reviews the body of the function.  Does python have something similar.  Which function in inspect would you use?  Thanks

Comment: @ZachRickers Try `inspect.getsource(function)` for a string of the function code. Otherwise look at the documentation I linked to and try some simple tests in ipython. Also please tag me if you comment again otherwise I don't get notifications for your replies.